# How to handle TCategoryButtons item visibility on search?

Tags: delphi, pascal, vcl

I'm using TCategoryButtons in my Delphi VCL project and I made a search procedure which is basically using loop for **MyCategoryButtons.Categories** and inside of this loop, I use second loop for each items with **MyCategoryButtons.Categories[i].Items**.

Here is my search code:

```
MyCategoryButtons.Categories[i].Items[j].CategoryButtons.Visible :=
            ContainsText(MyCategoryButtons.Categories[i].Items[j].Caption,
            SearchText);
```

When I follow up the code with debugger, It works well. But I can't update component visually. How can I update those visible items and how to hide item whose visible property value is false.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Category buttons (*TButtonItem*) have no *Visible* property as well as no *Enabled* property. They are always visible and enabled.

*MyCategoryButtons.Categories[i].Items[j].CategoryButtons* is the same as *MyCategoryButtons*, so setting its visibility will show/hide the complete control and not the individual button.

If you want to hide a *TButtonItem* you can rebuild the category and just don't create that button.